# Secure and Un-sercure ports

Tags: svn, ports

1) Adding a port to in-bound and out-bound exception list in firewall would make my machine vulnerable? 
2) What are the ports I should never add to exception list?
3) I would like to add 3690 to exception list for my svn will that make my system vulnerable?

Comment: This is off topic, but you should know that what matters is what is *running* on the ports. The ports themselves mean nothing. So figure out what services you want, and allow them, if you deem it to be of appropriate risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter on which port you run service but mostly often as which user you run those service and what that user can do.

What you need is restricted chrooted user that runs your svn repository if you want to be really safe.

I guess you are trying to run svn repository, your easiest bet is to create your repository as some user and tunnel your connections through ssh with `svn+ssh://svnuser@my.domain.com/home/myuser/REPOSITORY` 
style links.

If you want more svn users to access your service make svn group and add them to svn group,

```
chmod -R g+w /home/myuser/REPOSITORY
chgrp -R svngroup /home/myuser/REPOSITORY
```

and you're done

Answer (score 1):

This may be to generic in your cases, but have you considered setting up a VPN? (It's really easy with `openvpn`, and allows you to use your services just the way you use them in your LAN).